# Prove that for all integers $x$ and $y$, $x - y$ is odd if and only if $x + y$ is odd.

Tags: logic

the homework question I'm having trouble with is this one.

Write a detailed structured proof to prove that for all the integers $x$ and $y$, $x - y$ is odd if and only if $x + y$ is odd.

I have the proof format and structure down fine, its the proof part that is throwing me in circles.  What I worked out so far makes no sense so I think my understanding of it is flawed.

$2k+1$ is the definition of odd, so I use that when trying to prove it.
I'm going off the premise ($x - y$ is odd) $\Rightarrow$ ($x + y$ is odd)

Let $i \in \mathbb Z, $ be such that $x - y = 2i + 1$.

Then $x - y = 2i + 1$.

$2i = x - y - 1$.

$i = (x - y - 1)/2$.

$Let  p = i$.

$x + y = 2p + 1$.

$x + y = 2(x-y-1)/2 + 1$.

$x + y = x - y$.

So now I end up with an impossible case...
Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just note that $x+y = x-y+2y$.

Comment: why 2y? what does it represent?

Comment: You can't let $p=i$. This implies that $x-y=x+y$ or $-y=y$ so that $y=0$

Comment: $(x-y)+2y = x - y + y + y = x+y$. This shows that the difference between $x+y$ and $x-y$ is even, hence they are both odd or both even.

Comment: o ic. by adding + 2y it shows that odd + even = odd. at least I think that is what you are trying to explain to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x-y=2n+1$ then $x-y+2y=2n+1+2y$ or $x+y=2(n+y)+1$ showing $x+y$ is odd. For the argument in the other direction suppose $x+y=2n+1$ so that $x+y-2y=2n+1-2y$ and so $x-y=2(n-y)+1$ showing $x-y$ is odd.

Comment: I think I understand, but just to double check the part where x + y = 2(n + y) + 1 is the final manipulated state.  But what if n + y were to be odd.

Comment: It does not matter as long as they are integers(which they clearly are). Remember a number is odd if it can be written $2n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: so $ 2n + 1$ where $  n \in \mathbb Z$ is more of a statement where n has no real value?

Comment: $n$ only takes on a specific value when $x$ and $y$ do. Until then it just has to be thought of as some arbitrary integer.

Comment: I see, thank you for the help, it was really useful.